# Not able to create users using identities in Azure AD B2C using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create local account (like abc@yahoo.com) in Azure AD B2C using identities.

This is the document I followed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities.

Below is the request payload:

```json
{  
  "displayName": "John Smith",  
  "identities": [  
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yopmail.com" 
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile": { 
    "password": "Welcome@1",    
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false  
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

This is the response I'm getting:

```json
"error": {
  "code": "Request_BadRequest",
  "message": "Property userPrincipalName value is required but is empty or missing."
}
```

First it was throwing an error for `accountEnabled`, `mailNickname`, so added them in payload, then it was throwing an error for `userPrincipalName`.

If I add `userPrincipalName` in the payload, it was throwing an error like this:

```json
{
   "code": "Request_BadRequest",
   "message": "Property creationType is invalid."
}
```

How can I create users using identities in Azure AD B2C using Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Your request payload works absolutely fine on my test tenant. Can you check: 1. You're definitely using Microsoft Graph API (graph.microsoft.com) not Azure AD Graph API (graph.windows.net). 2. Your `issuer` is set to your actual tenant domain in both cases. 3. You're trying to create this user on a B2C tenant, not an Azure AD tenant.

Comment: Hey @DaveD thanks for the quick response, I am an associate of OP. We are using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users api in postman and GraphServiceClient in java but we are getting the same error with both trials. 2. Yes the issuer is set to our actual tenant. 3. We are trying to create user in Azure AD B2C tenant and not in Azure AD tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of attributes that work across all my tenants:

{
"accountEnabled": true,
"displayName": "Test User",
"mailNickname": "TestU",
"userPrincipalName": "TestU@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
"passwordProfile" : {
"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
"password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
}
}

Do you still get the error with something like this?

**Update**

For multiple identities, something like this works:

"identities": [
{
"signInType": "userName",
"issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
"issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
},
{
"signInType": "emailAddress",
"issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
"issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
},
{
"signInType": "federated",
"issuer": "facebook.com",
"issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
}
]

Comment: Hi rbrayb, we are using the same identities field to pass the user info for creating the user.I would like to give a brief explanation on what we have done:We have created an Azure AD B2C resource in an Azure subscription and registered a application in Azure AD B2C. We are then using our Directory (tenant) ID, Application (client) ID and client secret to call the api. We are using Microsoft Graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users with the payload shared above and getting error as mentioned above. Please take a look at the steps explained above and let us know if we missed something